# WireMock v 1.33 throws an "java.net.BindException: Address already in use", while v 1.28 does not with the same code

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I just tried to switch between WireMock 1.28 to 1.33 and out of a sudden I get exceptions thrown by Wiremock: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use"

The code to include WireMock looks like that:

```
@ClassRule
@Rule
public static WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(54321);
```

The same code actually works fine if I simple use WireMock 1.28.
Unfortunately v1.28 does not seem to have the possibility to configure a https port :(

How can I resolve that ?

Is there anything new in v1.33 that requires new setup code for WireMock or is this a know framework issue / unresolved bug in WireMock ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you remove "@ClassRule" WireMock stops complaining.

Still strange while the same code worked in previous versions. And it is even a recommendation to use that annotation if you havem ore then one test in a single JUnit file and don't want to start/stop WireMock in front of every test.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and to resolve it I used a dynamic port using the [code posted on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882431/2965993). In short, it creates a `WireMockRules` class which uses

```
wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort()
```