# How configure WireMock to use https (and a random port)?

Tags: java, junit, wiremock

I tried to set wiremock to run https on a random port:

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockServer = new WireMockRule(
    WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort()
);
```

but when I use this and I call `wireMockServer.httpsPort()` I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not listening on HTTPS port. Either HTTPS is not enabled or the WireMock server is stopped.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:150)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer.httpsPort(WireMockServer.java:184)
```

How do i set WireMock to use https?

*NOTE: I'm using version 2.14.0*

Comment: Did it work if you specified the HTTPS port (in which case you could randomise it outside with e.g. [the Maven build helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html))? How about if you *don't* also have an HTTP port?

Comment: Since you followed the documentation something else is wrong. Can you show all log output or more lines of your test class?

Comment: Can you show the test method where `wireMockServer.httpsPort()` is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

I used a `WireMockRules` class and had my test classes inherit from it

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit.WireMockRule;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class WiremockRules {
    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(
        wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().dynamicHttpsPort()
    );
}
```

and my `WiremockTest.java`

```
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.aResponse;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.get;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.urlEqualTo;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class WiremockTest extends WiremockRules {

    private String url;
    private String baseUrl = "http://localhost";

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        url = baseUrl + Integer.toString(wireMockRule.port()) + "/v1/test";
        
        stubFor(
            get(urlEqualTo(url))
                .willReturn(
                    aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the `baseUrl`?

Comment: Ah I had it set and forgot to include it in the code snippet. I'm positive I had it set to `http://localhost`